# prepareForSegue: is not called after tapping a row in UITableView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a `UITableview`, which has a list of cars. On selecting any row, a `UIViewcontroller` is to be shown, showing the details of the car selected.

However, `prepareForSegue:` is not getting called when I tap on any row in the Search Table View Controller.

After searching on the internet, I looked at a few examples and I tried to follow them to do this job, using `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowProductDetail" sender:nil];`
in my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method. It performed the job, but now I don't see a BACK button. I need the BACK button in the navigation bar in the new view controller, which is the selected one in the image:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What type of segue is that? The back button will only be shown for "push" types or styles respectively, not for modal nor custom.

Comment: Yes it is a push segue. Is there anyway to implement the Back button manually? since it is not being shown via didselectrow->prepareforsegue method

Comment: There must be something else wrong. Usually there is a back button as you have a navigation controller. And `prepareForSegue` should be called regardless whether the segue was initiated by storyboard or programmatically using `performSegueWithIdentfier:`

Comment: Make sure that the navigationItem.title property is set for the view controller that is performing the push. This is a common reason of not displaying the back button.

Comment: @danypata, this is not true. If there's no title, the back button will have the title "Back".

Comment: Are you hiding the navigation bar, or do you see it in that selected controller? I don't see anything wrong in your storyboard, and if you made that segue by dragging from the cell to the next controller, you shouldn't need any code to make the transition happen. You didn't say whether the segue actually happens? If so, and prepareForSegue isn't being called, then check your spelling of that method to make sure it's all correct.

Comment: @rdelmar , The segue does not happen actually, even though I have connected it, no transition happens when i select a row in the tableview. That is why I had to call the `performSegue` method in the `didSelectRowAtIndex` method. Any idea why the segue is not happening? And yes I dragged the segue from the cell to the view controller.

I appreciate everyone's help. Please help me figure out the problem. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I can't see anything wrong in your setup, so I can't really help any more unless you can send me the project.

Answer (score 1):

I was just missing my `cellIdentifier` for the prototype cell.